# UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default

Tags: java, android-studio, universal-image-loader

I am getting this error in my console.

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default ["http://mywebsite.com/mylocation/image.jpg"]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
```

I am trying to load images from my website into an android application.
Steps followed:
In build.gradle

```
dependencies {compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is the json output I am getting:

```
"image":"\"http:\\\/\\\/mywebsite.com\\\/mylocation\\\/image.jpg\""
```

In my ApplicationActivity.java

```
ImageView myImage
myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_id);
```

I tried stripping the url of all unnecessary parameters as below:

```
 imageUrl = url.replaceAll("\\[]\"", "");
 imageUrl = imageUrl.replace("\\/","/");
```

This is the code in ApplicationActivity.java that I used to try and load the image using UniversalImageLoader:

```
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
//
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config); 
Toast.makeText(single_event.this, imageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(imageUrl != null) {
       //Sets Image
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, myImage);

    }
  Log.d("URL", imageUrl);
```

The console log and the toast both return the correct url in quotes "http://mywebsite.com/mylocation/image.jpg"

Is there some configuration or setup i have missed?
Is there anything extra I hould do after `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, myImage);`
?

Please assist.

[Edit] This is the layout (below). If I specify the image source in the layout to be an image in drawable, then the image is loaded from the phone and all the java logic is ignored. If I remove the source, then nothing happens
                  `<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:id="@+id/image_id"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cnt"
                    android:src="@drawable/local_placeholder"
                   />`

Comment: I think that the regex inside `replaceAll("\\[]\"", "")` is wrong (it should not be a valid regex). You should have written it as: `replaceAll("[\\\\\"]", "")`

Comment: Hi I tried changing it to no avail. Perhaps the issue is in the layout? Please see edit.

Comment: did you strip the quotes from the URL? I mean, when you print it (inside the toast or in the LogCat), can you see the quotes? If the answer is yes then you need to remove them. (this is suggested by the second line of your question)

Comment: Yes the quotes are still there in the toast and the log. How do I remove them in the java for android?

Comment: I think that the regex provided before should work

Comment: replaceAll("[\\\\\"]", "") Is not working. I tried it and even modified it to imageUrl = url.replaceAll("\"[\\\\\"]\"", ""); but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you can do `replaceAll("\"", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        imageUrl = imageUrl.substring(1, imageUrl.length()-1);
```

to remove the quotes from "http://mywebsite.com/mylocation/image.jpg" solved the problem.